# Eclipse Synchronize with Repository programmatically

Tags: eclipse, svn, plugins

I'm trying to write a Plugin for Eclipse (Java).

If there are changes at the sourcecode (e.g. a bugfix), the plugin should realize which files of the eclipse-Project are changed (In order to run affected JUnit-Tests then). I'm planning to realize that with the SVN Syncronisation-Status.

So, if a file is different (outgoing change) to the "same" file at the repository, I know that the file was edited (of course).

I know that I can use the org.eclipse.team.* package/library.

I also found out that i can work with "SyncInfo" of this package.

But I really don't know how to implement this.

I think I have to define an "IResource" or "IProject" to give my plugin the information, which eclipse-project i want to test.

I wasn't able to find much useful info on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't define `IResource` or `IProject`. Instead, you should use the `Workbench` class to get one:

```
 IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
 IProject project = workspace.getRoot().getProject(...);
 IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
```

Now you can iterate over all the resources linked to the project.

That said, it might be better to implement `IncrementalProjectBuilder` and let Eclipse tell you what changed so you can simply run the unit tests for those elements. This should get you started on incremental builders: [Eclipse Help: Incremental project builders](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_builders.htm)

This way, you don't have to handle subversion at all; any change to the project, no matter who caused it, will trigger your builder and it can then decide what to do with the modification.

A good approach might be to collect tests to run in a queue and let a background worker process this queue.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for this for 1 month now. I tried to programm a plugin for eclipse, which is able to read the changeset of a Project ("working copy" of the repository).

What I've done now is an ugly work-around.

I used Runtime.exec() to run a cmd-command / Shell- command. If you install a svn-commandline Client, you can type svn status -v -u It gives you a list of all files of the working copy with the changeset info.

Than you can parse through the list to find all lines which start with "M" - for "modified" to get the Path of the changed file.